# Kotlin: Can't Import Module from Source

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, manjaro, arch

I was update my Android Studio to be Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.
When I want to import project's module, button finish always disable.
How to solve this problem ??

[image]